# What’s wrong with my Marigolds?

Tags: diseases

[image]

Not sure what’s wrong with my plants.  They get water, fertilizer and have been sprayed with Safer’s 3-in-1 as well.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what part of the world you're in, but this looks like thrips damage; one particular thrip is specific to Tagetes patula, which is the botanical name for your marigolds. You could try spraying with an insecticide that specifically treats thrips rather than the general purpose one you've tried, but unfortunately, even if it works, the visible damage on  your marigolds so far will still be there. Further information here https://nzacfactsheets.landcareresearch.co.nz/factsheet/InterestingInsects/French-marigold-thrips---Neohydatothrips-samayunkur.html